# How to monitor Mysql table changes by using ReactPHP

Tags: mysql, reactphp

I would like to monitor every table changes in a MySql table, (insert, update, delete), using ReactPHP. Is it possible? If yes how I can do it?

Comment: Perhaps using triggers in the database that updates a table, then a CRON job that checks the table.

Comment: I had done it, also with a nodejs script, but I'd like to do it with ReactPHP